# How to show that $ \left|\int_0^\infty \cos(ax)e^{-x^4} dx \right| \le \left|\int_0^\infty \cos(bx)e^{-x^4} dx \right|$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

How to show that 
\begin{align}
\left| \frac{\int_0^\infty \cos(ax)e^{-x^4} dx}{\int_0^\infty \cos(bx)e^{-x^4} dx} \right|  \le 1
\end{align}
 if $a\ge b \ge 0$.

This is what I did.

One has to show then that 
\begin{align}
 \frac{ \left|\int_0^\infty \cos(ax)e^{-x^4} dx \right| }{ \left|\int_0^\infty \cos(bx)e^{-x^4} dx \right|}  \le 1
\end{align}

Or that
\begin{align}
 \left|\int_0^\infty \cos(ax)e^{-x^4} dx \right|  \le \left|\int_0^\infty \cos(bx)e^{-x^4} dx \right|
\end{align}
But how to show the last inequality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot, because your inequality does not hold: just take $a=4$ and $b=3.5$.

If we take the function
$$ \psi: \xi \mapsto \int_{0}^{+\infty}\cos(\xi x)e^{-x^4}\,dx $$
this is its graph over $[0,10]$:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

and it is not monotonic in absolute value, even if fast-decaying.

Comment: Thanks.  You see the reason I thought that this inequality was correct is because I know it is true when the  exponential is of degree 1 or degree 2. That since $\int_0^\infty  \cos(ax) e^{-x} dx=\frac{1}{1+a^2}$ and $\int_0^\infty  \cos(ax) e^{-x^2} dx= 0.5*\sqrt{\pi} e^{a^2/4}$. With this we get \begin{align} \frac{\int_0^\infty  \cos(ax) e^{-x} }{\int_0^\infty  \cos(bx) e^{-x} }  =\frac{1+b^2}{1+a^2} \\  \frac{\int_0^\infty  \cos(ax) e^{-x^2} }{\int_0^\infty  \cos(bx) e^{-x^2} }  =e^{\frac{b^2-a^2}{4}}\end{align} Both of which are less than 1 if $a>b$. So, why is it not the same for $x^4$?

Comment: @Boby: because the Fourier transform is slightly oscillating, while that does not happen in the other cases.

Comment: Could you explain more along the lines of Fourier analysis? I  am very curios.  Also, is it correct to say that if we exponent $x^k$ then the inequality is true for all $0< k\le2$ ?

Comment: Interesting fact, it probably deserves a separate question.

Comment: Ok. I will post a new question.

Comment: see this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846072/bounds-on-fk-a-b-frac-int-0-infty-cosa-x-e-xk-dx-int-0-infty You can also modify it any way you want.

Comment: @Boby: thank you. A very interesting (and probably quite hard) problem has born here.

Comment: I am very glad you liked this problem.  At first, I did not realize that Fourier analysis would be at the heart of this problem.  Thank you for all of your ideas.  It seems like you are the person with the correct experience and set of skills to study this.  In case if you decided to pursue this problem, let me know if you get anywhere. I will be very interested in seeing your results.