# Fourier cosine transforms of Schwartz functions and the Fejer-Riesz theorem

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-inequality, fourier-transform

This question spanned from [a previous interesting one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846072/bounds-on-fk-a-b-frac-int-0-infty-cosa-x-e-xk-dx-int-0-in?lq=1).
 Let $k$ be a real number greater than $2$ and
$$\varphi_k(\xi) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\cos(\xi x) e^{-x^k}\,dx $$
the Fourier cosine transform of a function in the [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space).

> Is is possible to use [the Fejér-Riesz theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fej%C3%A9r-Riesz_theorem) or some variation of it,
>  to prove that $\varphi_k(\xi)<0$ for some $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: If the integral over $[0,\pi/2\xi]$ is not smaller than that over $[\pi/2\xi,3\pi/2\xi]$, then $\varphi_k(\xi)$ is never negative. Have you looked at that?

Comment: @TrialAndError: that is clear, but I actually want to prove the opposite, that for some xi the integral is negative, and my conjecture is supported by numerical simulations.

Comment: Do you believe $\varphi_k(\xi)$ to be negative for all $\xi$, or what did you have in mind for F-R?

Comment: I believe what I wrote, namely that such a function is negative for some xi. It obviously cannot be negative for all xi, by just considering the behaviour at the origin.

Comment: So how were you thinking of using F-R then?

Comment: Extend FJ to Fourier cosine transforms and prove that such a transform cannot be a square, so it has to be negative somewhere. Or, as an alternative approach, prove the same through Sturm sequences.

Comment: Note the  integral we have can be written in term of Fox-Write function \begin{align}  \int_0^\infty \cos(tx) e^{-x^k}dx= \Psi_{1,1}  \left[ \begin{array}{l} (1/k,2/k) \\ (1/2,1)\end{array} ; -\frac{ \left( t\right)^2}{4}\right] \end{align}. You can find this result here: http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~goran/research-reports/psrr18-2009.pdf    . So the in this case the quesiont boils down what values of $k$ does Fox-Write function have or does not have zeros.

Comment: I've now posted an answer supplying a proof of the result that @Boby asked about earlier (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846072: the cosine transform is a decreasing function for $0<k<2$) using the same source.

Comment: @thanks. Saw it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One proof is given in the paper

> Noam D. Elkies, Andrew M. Odlyzko, and Jason A. Rush: On the packing densities of superballs and other bodies *Invent. Math.* **105** (1991), 613-639.

Instead of Fejér-Riesz, we use the Fourier inversion formula directly.
Assume for contradiction that $\phi_k(\xi) \geq 0$ for all $\xi$.
Then for all $x$ we would have
$$
0 \leq \int_0^\infty \phi_k(\xi) \, (1 - \cos (\xi x))^2 \, dx
 = \frac12 \int_0^\infty \phi_k(\xi) \, (3 - 4 \cos (\xi x) + \cos (2\xi x)) \, dx,
$$
which means
$$
3 - 4 e^{-x^k} + e^{-(2x)^k} \geq 0
$$
for all $x$.  But for $x$ near $0$ we may write
$e^{-x^k} = 1 - \epsilon$ and 
$e^{-(2x)^k} = (1 - \epsilon)^{2^k} = 1 - 2^k \epsilon + O(\epsilon^2)$,
so 
$$
3 - 4 e^{-x^k} + e^{-(2x)^k} 
= 3 - 4(1-\epsilon) + (1 - 2^k \epsilon + O(\epsilon^2))
= (4 - 2^k) \epsilon + O(\epsilon^2).
$$
Thus $3 - 4 e^{-x^k} + e^{-(2x)^k}$ becomes negative for small $x$
once $2^k > 4$, which is equivalent to $k=2$, 
and we have our desired contradiction.

Comment: That is just brilliant: simple and effective. It reminded me of Hadamard's proof that $\zeta(s)\neq 0$ for $\text{Re}(s)=1$. Good work and many, many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you!  Indeed it's the same $(3, -4, +1)$ trick,
as I note in my lectures on analytic number theory: see Exercise 2 
on the last page of the chapter on the zero-free region,
http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M229.15/free.pdf .

Comment: Any way we can to find a pdf of your paper Noam D. Elkies, Andrew M. Odlyzko, and Jason A. Rush: On the packing densities of superballs and other bodies Invent. Math. 105 (1991), 613-639.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Also, do you think we can say something about distribution of zeros. For example, if $t_0$ is a zero does it mean that $t_1=t_0+2\pi$ is also a zero.

Comment: Re: "Any way we can find a pdf of your paper . . ." to my surprise, yes, since it appeared long enough ago to be on GDZ: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002108941
That paper also gives an asymptotic expansion for the Fourier transform (Lemma 10 on page 634); there are infinitely many zeros, but they're not spaced as regularly as an arithmetic progression -- the case "$k=\infty$" is misleading.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies  Thank you very much. I will definitely read you paper now.   In you paper, do you talk about distribution of zeros?