# Expressing an lntegral in Standard, Nonstandard Functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, improper-integrals, distribution-theory, fourier-transform

Let $\alpha \in (0,2]$. For stable symmetric distributions with characteristic function of the form $e^{-\vert t \vert ^{\alpha}}$, their PDFs are given by the Fourier transform
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int _{-\infty} ^ {\infty}e^{-\vert t \vert ^{\alpha}-itx}dt,$$
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

Question: How can $f(x)$ or$$F(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int _{-\infty} ^ xe^{-\vert t \vert ^{\alpha}-itx}dt,$$

be expressed in terms of standard (or non-standard) mathematical functions? I know only of a few choices of $\alpha$ for which $f$ can be simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fourier transform of $e^{-|x|^k}$ is given by a [Fox-Write function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function),  that is a generalized [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). To call them *standard* or not is just a matter of taste, in my humble opinion, but they have remarkable properties: see, for instance, [a recent question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1847213/fourier-cosine-transforms-of-schwartz-functions-and-the-fejer-riesz-theorem) and Noam Elkies' excellent answer.

Comment: (Question updated) Mathematica gives a simpler looking expression (which I am skeptical of).

Comment: Probably because you did not type the imaginary unit through esc+ii+esc so a relevant piece was parsed as a constant.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first time using Mathematica. I fixed the $i$, but the result is the same according to Mathematica.

Comment: How can t appear in the integral? Put a space between i, t and x.