# Given $U$ with known PDF, find $W$ independent of $U$ such that $U+W$ is distributed like $2U$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, convolution, independence

> Let $U$ denote a random variable with PDF $$f_U(u)=ce^{-u\sqrt{u}}\,\mathbf 1_{u>0}$$ Does there exist a random variable $W$ independent of $U$ such that $U+W$ is distributed like $2U$?

This question is related to something I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877093/existence-of-additive-transformation-of-random-variables).

In other words, can we find a random variable $W$ such that 
\begin{align}
2 U' =U+W
\end{align}
where $W$ and $U$ are independent and $U'$ has the same distribution as $U$.

Comment: It is the same question as *is $2U_1 - U_2$ independent  of $U_2$* ?. I think it suffices to take $U_1$ and $U_2$ independent to have a counter example.

Comment: @Gribouillis thanks for you comment. Perhaps you can elaborate more by putting your thoughts as an answer.

Comment: Now that you received an answer to your other question, did you try to apply it here?

Comment: @Gribouillis Of course assuming that $U_1$ should be independent of $U_2$ is putting such a severe constraint on the problem that it becomes without solution. But this is not the question asked at all...

Comment: @Did then the question should be Is it possible to find a variable $W$ independent from $U_2$ such that $(W+U_2)/2$ follows the same law ? As the question is  formulated, the answer is *no in general* (that is to say in general, given 2 variables following this law, there is no W). Of course, *in general* is not defined :)

Comment: @Gribouillis The question is clearly: *Let $U$ with PDF $f_U$, does there exist $W$ independent of $U$ such that $U+W$ is distributed like $2U$?*

Comment: @Did Adding an independent variable to obtain a certain law is indeed very different from adding an independent variable to obtain a certain variable, this point could be clarified by the OP.

Comment: @Did would this work take $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ this a convex function. Then by the answer here $E[ f(2 U_1)] \ge  E[ f(U_2)]$ this implis that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \ge 1$. Which leads to  a contradiction?

Comment: Not directly since you would need to appeal to $f(x)$ for $x>0$ and for $x<0$ and $f$ is not convex on any open interval containing $0$.

Comment: @Did is there a better choice of $f(x)$.  Because I don't think that $f(x)=|x|^p, p\ge1$ will work.

Comment: You should first center your variables, meaning that you would have $$E\big[f\big(2(U_1 - E[U_1])\big)\big]\ge E\big[f(U_2 - E[U_2])\big].$$ Try $f(x) = (x-c)^+= \max(x-c,0)$ for different $c$.

Comment: @zhoraster I tried the function that you suggested by I do no get a contradiction.

Comment: Well, if the inequality is true for each $c$, then there is the convex dominance, so you should try other approaches.

Comment: @zhoraster but is in it also possible that such a $W$ exists?

Comment: I doubt it does. By the way, it seems that for a centered $U$, $U\preceq_{cv} 2U$ always. So my suggestion was doomed to fail. Sorry for that.

Comment: @zhoraster No problem thanks for the ideas. Do you have an intuition for why such a $W$ might not exist.

Comment: Yes, I do have an intuition. It is, however, just an intuition, so hard to explain. It may as well be wrong. Speaking of ideas, there is another approach based on Laplace transforms. It is spiritually related to characteristic functions. I'll update my answer elsewhere. By the way, you didn't explain your motivation yet.

Comment: Boby: Why the interest for the PDF on $u>0$ proportional to $\exp(-u\sqrt{u})$?

Comment: @Did sorry, I didn't understand what you meant?

Comment: Really? Again: Why are you interested in this specific PDF?

Comment: @Did  There is no particular reason.  I am trying to generate a few examples to see how to approach this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877093/existence-of-additive-transformation-of-random-variables   The exponential seemed like a good choice.

Comment: @Did  To motivation this example, I add some more details and examples to the question I asked before: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877093/existence-of-additive-transformation-of-random-variables

Comment: I doubt many people would call this *motivation*, this is more a near duplicate question...

Comment: @Did I was wondering if you could take a look at this question that I recently asked I give any suggestion on how to show it. The question is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2155030/e-sqrt1-t-v-sqrtt-w-sqrt1-t-vz-1-sqrtt-wz-2-e-sqrt1

Comment: @Boby What is your source for it?

Comment: @Did In communication theory, this comes up in the context of something called maximum ratio combining. The basic ideas that it is enough to look at a linear combination of outputs of two antennas instead of each output individually. However, I think this only true when signals are assumed to be Gaussian.   I wanted to see that this only optimal if random variables a Gaussian.   Sorry, if this is too brief, I will be happy to fill in more details if you want.   It would be great if you could point me in some direction of how to approach this problem.

Comment: @zhoraster you mentioned that you had an idea of using Laplace transform. Do you still  think it will work?

Answer (score 0):

In general the answer is such a $W$ doesn't exist.

To see this let assume $U_1$ and $U_2$ are independent and $W$ exists. Then $$U_2 = 2U_1 - W$$ but $2U_1 - W$ is independent of $U_2$ by assumption so $U_2$ is independent of itself hence $U_2$ is constant what is a contradiction.

So such a $W$ cannot exist.

Comment: It seems that your argument applies to any $U_1$ and $U_2$ and does not depend on the properties of the pdf.  But then we can take $U_1$ and $U_2$ to be standard normal and we can have $2U_1=W+U_2$ by taking $W \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.

Comment: The argument applies to any *independent* $U_1$ and $U_2$. If $W$ and $U_2$ follow ${\cal N}(0,1)$ and are independent, then $U_1=(W+ U_2)/2$ follows the same law but it is not independent from $U_2$.

Comment: Gono: Please see comments to main.

Comment: Note: The question has been edited since this answer was written; the question once contained $U_1$ and $U_2$ like this answer.