# Steepest descent of integrand with a movable saddle?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, asymptotics

I want to apply the steepest descent method to the following integration:
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2 + i \sqrt{x^2 + 1} \cdot \lambda } dx
$$

It has movable saddle so I need to transform it into the standard form, something like

$$
\int_C g(z) e^{\lambda f(z) } dz
$$

I know for Gamma function:
$$ \Gamma(x+1)= \int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{x} dt =\int_0^\infty e^{-t + x \ln t} dt $$
letting $t = x s$ transforms it into standard form. And for Airy function:

$$Ai(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i (t^3/3 + x t)} dt $$

letting $t = \sqrt{x} z$ does the trick.

However, no change of variable seems to transform my integration into the standard form. For this reason I can not proceed at all. Any hint or suggestion ? Thanks!

Comment: You need to find the saddle point (in general there can be more than one, in that case there will be one that yields the dominant contribution). If there is a saddle point at $z = z_0$, then the contour is deformed to move through $z_0$. Then write the integrand as $f(z_0 + u)$ and integrate over $u$,  you define a new variable $w$ such that $f(z_0 + u) = \exp(-w^2)$, becomes exactly a Gaussian. This then has to be multiplied by the Jacobian $\frac{du}{dw}$.

Comment: defining $g(x)=e^{-x^2}$? Maybe this is too simple but definitly worth a try

Comment: @AntonioVargas i came away with this cheap trick a few times, but i have no idea when it works...:(

Comment: Set $x^2+1=y$. The integral in question transforms into

$$
I=e\int_1^{\infty}dy\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2-1}}e^{-y^2}e^{i\lambda y}
$$

after a rescaling $y\rightarrow\lambda y$ this reads

$$
I=e\lambda^2\int_{1/\lambda}^{\infty}dy\frac{y}{\sqrt{\lambda^2y^2-1}}e^{-\lambda^2(y^2+iy)}
$$

which is not too far away from a form where classic steepest descent method can be applied (i think @AntonioVargas has elaborated somewhere on this site on integrals of this type, where the prefactor of the exponential is a slowly varying fiunction of $\lambda$)

Comment: @tired This does not work. If you take $exp(-x^2)$ in separation, the next step of asymptotics is essentially stationary phase, and the stationary point would be $x = 0$, then $exp(-x^2) = exp(0) = 1$, which is saying the term $exp(-x^2)$ has no effect. However, this conclusion is not right.

Comment: @CountIblis I suppose you are suggesting directly replace $x$ by $z$, and start deforming the original integration path $[0, \infty]$, to a steepest descent one?

Comment: @tired Hi tired, could you give me an example where your trick works, I am trying to get some hint. Thanks.

Comment: @taozi i am quiet busy today but hoepfully dig a bit deeper into the problem tomorrow. i think the trick works if  the highest power in the exponent is imaginary and the lower power is negative real, see here for an example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853545/limit-of-lim-t-to-infty-frac-int-0-infty-cosx-t-e-xkdx-int-0/2048134#2048134. I guess after some deformation this scenario might also occur in your case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us here sketched a derivation.

1. OP's integral has a saddle point at $z=0$ with angular steepest descent  direction $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Therefore, inspired by the [method of steepest descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent), we rewrite OP's integral as
   $$I(\lambda) ~:=~\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\!\mathrm{d}z~ 
   \exp\left\{-z^2+i\lambda\sqrt{1+z^2}\right\}
   ~=~ \frac{e^{i\lambda}}{2}J(\lambda),\qquad \lambda~>~0, \tag{1}$$
   where 
   $$\begin{align}J(\lambda) ~:=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\mathrm{d}z~ \exp\left\{-z^2+i\lambda\left(\sqrt{1+z^2}-1\right)\right\} \cr
   ~\stackrel{z=\frac{u}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\exp\left(\frac{i\pi}{4}\right)}{=}&
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\exp\left(\frac{i\pi}{4}\right)
   K(\lambda),\end{align}\tag{2} $$ 
   where
   $$ K(\lambda)~:=~\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\mathrm{d}u~ 
   \exp\left\{-\frac{iu^2}{\lambda}-f_{\lambda}(u)\right\},\tag{3}$$
   and where
   $$ -f_{\lambda}(u)~:=~i\lambda\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{iu^2}{\lambda}}-1\right)
   ~=~-\frac{u^2}{2} + \frac{iu^4}{8\lambda}+ O(u^6\lambda^{-2}).\tag{4} $$
2. Let us define the non-negative function
   $$ f(u)~:=~\frac{u^2}{2}. \tag{5} $$
   Clearly 
   $$  f_{\lambda}(u)~\longrightarrow~ f(u)\quad\text{for}\quad\lambda~\to~ \infty \tag{6}$$
   $u$-pointwise.
3. We note that the real part is given by
   $$ {\rm Re}~ f_{\lambda}(u)~=~\lambda\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{u^4}{\lambda^2}}-1}{2}} .\tag{7}$$
   Define a non-negative function 
   $$ g(u)~:=~ \frac{|u|}{2}~\theta(|u|\!-\!\sqrt{2}) , \tag{8}$$
   where $\theta$ denotes the [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).
   One may show that
   $$\forall\lambda\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\forall u\in\mathbb{R}:~~ 
   {\rm Re}~ f_{\lambda}(u) ~\geq~ g(u),\tag{9}$$
   because
   $$\forall\lambda\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\forall u\geq\sqrt{2}:~~ 
   \sqrt{1+\frac{u^4}{\lambda^2}}-1  ~\geq~ \frac{u^2}{2\lambda^2}.\tag{10}$$
4. It follows that $\exp\left\{-g(u)\right\}$ is a majorant function for the integrand (3). [Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) then shows that
   the corresponding integral (3) satisfies
   $$ K(\lambda)~\longrightarrow~ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\mathrm{d}u~ 
   \exp\left\{-f(u)\right\}~=~\sqrt{2\pi} \quad \text{for} \quad\lambda~\to~ \infty. \tag{11} $$
5. Next we can estimate corrections to any order in $1/\lambda$ we like. E.g.
   $$\begin{align}K(\lambda)~\stackrel{(3)+(4)}{=}&\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\mathrm{d}u~
   \exp\left\{-\left(\frac{i}{\lambda}+\frac{1}{2}\right)u^2\right\}
   \left(1 +\frac{iu^4}{8\lambda} + O(\lambda^{-2})\right)\cr
   ~=~&\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\frac{i}{\lambda}+\frac{1}{2}}}+\frac{i}{8\lambda}\underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\mathrm{d}u~\exp\left\{-\frac{u^2}{2}\right\}u^4}_{=3\sqrt{2\pi}} + O(\lambda^{-2})\cr
   ~=~&\sqrt{2\pi}\left(1 -\frac{5i}{8\lambda} + O(\lambda^{-2})\right) ,\end{align}\tag{12}$$ 
   and so forth. Hence OP's integral (1) has an asymptotic expansion

   > $$ I(\lambda)~\sim~ e^{i\lambda}\frac{1+i}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}\left(1 -\frac{5i}{8\lambda} + O(\lambda^{-2})\right)\quad \text{for}\quad \lambda~\to~\infty .\tag{13} $$

Comment: Hi @Qmechanic Your solution is very beautiful. I still have two questions. 1> what's the rational behind the form of substitution in equation 2, esp. the $\exp(i \pi/4)?$ 2> In equation 12 did you separate the exponent into two groups and Taylor expand the second group? If so, why $\int_R du \exp \{-(i/\lambda + 1/2)u^2 \} u^4 = -5 \sqrt{2\pi}$?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer but too long for a comment.

It appears that the saddle point at $x=0$ is dominant. There are two more but they can be avoided (and they possibly lie on the branch cuts of the integrand anyway---that would be bad).

If we make the substitution $x = u/\sqrt{\lambda}$ we get

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \exp\left\{-x^2+i\lambda\sqrt{x^2+1}\right\}dx &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \int_0^\infty \exp\left\{-\frac{u^2}{\lambda}+i\lambda\sqrt{\frac{u^2}{\lambda}+1}\right\}du \\
&= \frac{e^{i\lambda}}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \int_0^\infty \exp\left\{-\frac{u^2}{\lambda}-i\lambda \left( 1-\sqrt{\frac{u^2}{\lambda}+1} \right) \right\}du.
\end{align}
$$

Numerically,

$$
\int_0^\infty \exp\left\{-\frac{u^2}{\lambda}-i\lambda \left( 1-\sqrt{\frac{u^2}{\lambda}+1} \right) \right\}du \to \int_0^\infty \exp\{iu^2/2\}\,du = \frac{1+i}{2}\sqrt{\pi}
$$

as $\lambda \to \infty$, but I'm not sure how to show it at the moment. This would imply that

$$
\int_0^\infty \exp\left\{-x^2+i\lambda\sqrt{x^2+1}\right\}dx \sim \frac{(1+i)e^{i\lambda}}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}
$$

as $\lambda \to \infty$.

Comment: I did a quick check of your solution in Mathematica, it appears remarkably accurate, I need more time to understand how and why the substitution works.

Comment: Unfortunately, the result appears to be the same if you throw away the $e^{-x^2}$ term right at the beginning.

Comment: @Taozi, I used this substitution because near $x=0$ we have $$-x^2 + i\lambda\sqrt{x^2+1} = i \lambda +\left(-1+\frac{i \lambda }{2}\right) x^2 + O(x^3),$$ and substituting $x = u/\sqrt{\lambda}$ asymptotically removes the $\lambda$-dependence from the coefficient of $x^2$.