# Asymptotics of $\int^\infty_0 e^{-(r+1)u}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-u}\right)\,du$ as $r \to \infty$.

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Can someone explain the following asymptotics, through Watson’s Lemma or through another argument?

> \begin{align}
> \int^\infty_0 e^{-(r+1)u}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-u}\right)\,du \sim \frac{\pi}{2(r+1)^2},\qquad r\to \infty.
> \end{align}

Comment: what about reading up something about Watsons Lemma for yourself (wikipedia maybe) and show some own effort? we are no math chatbots here, our time is valuable

Comment: I have tried but I’m not able to understand anything on wikipedia and there are no videos explaining it. I’m currently studying in 12th class we aren’t taught this in school either. @tired

Comment: Because of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584442/evaluate-lim-r-to-infty-frac-int-0-pi-2xr-1-cos-x-mathrm-dx-int-0)?

Comment: Yes, I wasn’t able to understand that part in any of the proofs. @Rohan

Answer (score 2):

By just integrating by parts twice one gets, as $r \to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
&\int^\infty_0 e^{-(r+1)u}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-u}\right)\,du
\\\\&=\left[ \frac{e^{-(r+1)u}}{-(r+1)}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-u}\right)\right]_0^\infty
+\frac{\pi}{2(r+1)}\int^\infty_0 e^{-(r+2)u}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-u}\right)\,du
\\\\&=\color{red}{0}+\frac{\pi}{2(r+1)}\left(\left[ \frac{e^{-(r+2)u}}{-(r+2)}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-u}\right)\right]_0^\infty
-\frac{\pi}{2(r+2)}\int^\infty_0 e^{-(r+3)u}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-u}\right)\,du \right)
\\\\&=\frac{\pi}{2(r+1)(r+2)}+o\left(\frac1{(r+1)^2}\right)
\\\\&=\frac{\pi}{2(r+1)^2}+o\left(\frac1{(r+1)^2}\right).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: How did you simplify the last integral?

Comment: Since $|\cos v |\le1$, the last integral satisfies $$ \left|\int^\infty_0 e^{-(r+3)u} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-u}\right)\,du\right|  \le  \int^\infty_0 e^{-(r+3)u}\,du=\frac1{(r+3)}$$ tending to $0$ as $r \to \infty$.

Comment: @VarunMaddipati Do you get it?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot @Olivier Oloa

Answer (score 0):

If we want to make it match [the formula for Watson's lemma on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma), we start by writing

$$
\int^\infty_0 e^{-(r+1)u}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-u}\right)\,du = \int^\infty_0 e^{-ru} e^{-u}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-u}\right)\,du = \int^\infty_0 e^{-ru} \varphi(u)\,du,
$$

where

$$
\varphi(u) := e^{-u}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-u}\right).
$$

Now $\varphi(0) = 0$ and $\varphi'(0) = \pi/2$, so we can write

$$
\varphi(u) = ug(u),
$$

where

$$
g(u) = u^{-1} e^{-u}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-u}\right)
$$

and $g(0) = \pi/2 \neq 0$. In the notation of wikipedia we have $\lambda = 1$.

Thus, taking only the first term ($n=0$) of the asymptotic expansion from the article, we get

$$
\int^\infty_0 e^{-(r+1)u}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-u}\right)\,du \sim \frac{g^{(0)}(0)\, \Gamma(1+0+1)}{0!\, r^{1+0+1}} = \frac{\pi}{2r^2}
$$

as $r \to \infty$ since

$$
g^{(0)}(0) = g(0) = \pi/2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \Gamma(2) = 1! = 1.
$$

---

To conclude that

$$
\int^\infty_0 e^{-(r+1)u}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-u}\right)\,du \sim \frac{\pi}{2(r+1)^2}
$$

we just need to note that

$$
\frac{\pi}{2r^2} \sim \frac{\pi}{2(r+1)^2}
$$

as $r \to \infty$.