# Fourier transform of $\exp(-z^k)$: How can one quatify its decay?

Tags: fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

Consider the Fourier transform of $\exp(-z^k)$ where $k$ is a positive integer. As the function is analytic, I expect it to 
have exponential decay at infinity. Is there some known theorem giving a  quantitative estimate for that decay?
(Some variant of the Paley–Wiener theorem useful for this case?)

Off course if k=2 we get (up to a constants) the same function, but 
I don't expect an explicit formula for other values of k.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2048134).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to restrict yourself to $k$ even, as for odd $k$ the function is not integrable and thus the Fourier transform does not exists (at least in a conventional sense).

So you are interested in the value of
$$ F_n(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i k x - x^{2n}}\,dx $$
for $|k|\to \infty$. The saddle point $x_*$ is given by the solution of
$$ \frac{d}{dx} (i k x - x^{2n}) = i k  - 2n x^{2n-1} =0\,.$$
We obtain
$$ x_*= c_1 k^{\frac{1}{2n-1}}\,.$$
So the dominating behavior of the integral is given by
$$ F_n(k) \sim  c_2 \exp\left(-c_3 k^{\frac{2n}{2n-1} } \right)$$
where $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are constants which can be determined by applying the method of stationary phase carefully.

Comment: You are right about your observation! For odd k it should be exp(-|z|^k) (but then the function is not analytic anymore). I also had forgotten about the method of stationary phase! Many thanks!

Comment: To apply the steepest descent method to this problem, you have to choose a contour going through two complex critical points. You get two complex exponentials, yielding sine/cosine terms. It's not exactly correct to say that $F$ is asymptotically equivalent to this expression $G$: $F/G$ does not tend to $1$, $F$ and $G$ have zeroes at different points.

Comment: How to apply the method of stationary phase precisely, can you give me some reference? Thanks a lot.