# definite integral with complex solution

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, substitution

this integral is proving to be very challenging so help is required:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\beta x^{\beta -1} e^{-x^{\beta}} dx$$

This has been my approach so far:
$$\beta \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^{\beta}} x^{\beta -1} dx$$
The next logical step in this was to perform a $u$ substitution having $u = x^{\beta}$ and $du = \beta x^{\beta}$ but that didnt not help simplify the intergral and neither would if i use $u$ to be $(tx-x^{\beta})$ so I am pretty much stuck.
Also I am worried about what would happen to the limits of the Integrals if I use $u = x^{\beta}$
help please?

Comment: Are $t$ and $\beta$ fixed?

Comment: is a dx or dt ? Note that $du =\beta x^{\beta -1}$ for $u=x^{\beta}$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha cannot solve this, so you need to explain why you think there is a closed solution.

Comment: @isham it is dx mate sorry

Comment: @Klaus Wolfram Alpha was my first port of call Klaus. this is why i am saying that this integration seems to be more complex than usual. there is a closed solution because i need to proof that  $$E(X^r) = \Gamma(\frac{r}{\beta}+1)$$

Comment: $$\int_0^{\infty } \exp (t x) \beta  x^{\beta -1} \exp \left(-x^{\beta }\right) \, dx=\sum _{j=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{t^j \Gamma \left(1+\frac{j}{\beta }\right)}{j!}=\Psi_{1,1}  \left[ \begin{array}{l} (1,\frac{1}{\beta }) \\ (1,0)\end{array} ; t\right]$$ See:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880261/zeros-of-fox-wright-function

Comment: I think this can be solved similar to this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586898/how-to-evaluate-this-notoriously-hard-exponential-integral