# First positive zero of a function $f(x)= \int_0^\infty \cos(tx) e^{-t^4} dt$.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I am interested in estimating the position of the first positive zero of the following function
\begin{align}
f(x)= \int_0^\infty \cos(tx) e^{-t^4} dt.
\end{align}

For the story of this question please see [Q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853545/limit-of-lim-t-to-infty-frac-int-0-infty-cosx-t-e-xkdx-int-0), [Q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846072/bounds-on-fk-a-b-frac-int-0-infty-cosa-x-e-xk-dx-int-0-in), [Q3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1847213/fourier-cosine-transforms-of-schwartz-functions-and-the-fejer-riesz-theorem).

Numerical simulation seem to suggest that the zero is around $3.4$.

The end goal of this question is to find a way of estimating zeros of a more general function 
\begin{align}
f(x)= \int_0^\infty \cos(tx) e^{-t^k} dt.
\end{align}

for $k>2$. However, as can be seen from [Q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853545/limit-of-lim-t-to-infty-frac-int-0-infty-cosx-t-e-xkdx-int-0) the function can behave differently, depending if $k$ is odd or even.  To reduce complexity, I therefore, decided to focus on a specific case of $k=4$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  Integral of $f(x)$ or the integral of $\cot(xt) e^{-t^4}$??

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1847213/fourier-cosine-transforms-of-schwartz-functions-and-the-fejer-riesz-theorem

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Hey Jak. Yes, I was going to add this. If you remember a while back we formulated all this together.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: the given function has a real zero close to $x=3.5$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Well, if you'll excuse me... I think I'll be taking my leave on this question XD

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt No. Come on stay...

Answer (score 0):

In Maple:

`F:= int(cos(t*x)*exp(-t^4),t=0..infinity) assuming x>0;`
$$ 1/4\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {\pi} \left( {\frac {\sqrt {\pi}}{\Gamma \left( 3/
4 \right) }{\mbox{$_0$F$_2$}(\ ;\,1/2,3/4;\,{\frac {{x}^{4}}{256}})}}-
1/4\,{\frac {\sqrt {2}\Gamma \left( 3/4 \right) {x}^{2}}{\sqrt {\pi}}
{\mbox{$_0$F$_2$}(\ ;\,5/4,3/2;\,{\frac {{x}^{4}}{256}})}} \right) 
$$

`fsolve(F,x=0..4);`
$$3.453464128$$

Comment: Thank you.  I am however interested in providing a result that would give lower and upper bound on $x_0$ and is more analytic.

Comment: You might be able to get bounds by considering the ratio of those two hypergeometric functions...

Comment: Sure. But I was hoping for an approach that can be extended to any $k$.  We are kind of lucky that we can come up with a closed form expression of an integral for $k=4$.